# ER-Diagram Company key

Tags: mysql

The following [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu8Gz.jpg) is **ERD** for one application or one business. If you have used QuickBooks youll know that it has starting form called company so in one application we can create many companies and maintain company accounts

if I add a column companyid to all table then I can add many companies in one application

what is the good practice:

1. Adding company key and exacting company info with company key
2. Creating database for each company if thrs 100 companies 100 mysql databases

please advice !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a separate database per company is almost assuredly *not* what you want to do (unless you have a really good reason to need to do so).  Adding a company_id to your tables and ensuring that columns you query against are indexed with company_id along with whatever other column you will typically be querying would be wise.

You'll also need to ensure that your application is designed to correctly inadvertent (or purposeful) access from one company to another company's data.

EDIT - Now that I see your ERD has been added:  I would add a "company" table containing a company_id, name, and whatever other data you like, then ensure your other tables have an additional company_id field as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to maintain all companies' businesses and accounts within the same application, then there is no need to create a database for each company, just add a `Companies` table, then add a foreign key `company_id` to the other database tables